# .htaccess Redirect access folder by folder

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a directory like:

```
> public_html/
> |-- demo1/
> |   |-- templates/
> |   |   |-- temp1/ (all html for demo purpose)
> |   |   |-- temp2/ (all html for demo purpose)
> |   |   |-- temp3/ (all html for demo purpose)
```

demo1 is the main content of `mydomain.local` and i used this htaccess somehow i tried this to access temp1, temp2, and temp3 but doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo1/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ demo1/index.html [L]
```

What I need to do is to access temp1 without displaying the `demo1/templates/`

for example

```
http://mydomain.local/temp1
```

not

```
http://mydomain.local/demo1/templates/temp1
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes @hjpotter92, for the main display of mydomain.local is inside demo1 and i used the following htaccess

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo1/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ viidemo/index.html [L]`

Comment: Please include such information in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo1/templates/$1 [L]
```

Comment: page layout means your css , images and js are not working ??

Comment: yes, those are not working also it pulls the index of `demo1`

Comment: You need to exclude css , images and js by using RewriteCond

Comment: You need to exclude css , images and js by using RewriteCond , try this    `RewriteCond $1 !^(images|css|js|captcha|public)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo1/templates/$1 [L]`